# Comparing @Now to a Date/Time field?

Tags: xpages

How do I compare @Now to a data / time value in a document?   This is what I have

```
      var ProjectActiveTo:NotesDateTime = doc.getItemValueDateTimeArray("ProjectActiveTo")[0];

    var ProjectExpired;

    var d1:Date  = @Now();

    if (d1 > ProjectActiveTo.toJavaDate())      
    {
        dBar.info("Today: " + d1 + " > " + ProjectActiveTo.toJavaDate());
        ProjectExpired = true;
    }
    else
    {
        dBar.info("Today: " + d1 + " < " + ProjectActiveTo.toJavaDate());
        ProjectExpired = false;
    }
```

But this always seems to return false.  I printed out some diagnostic messages.

Today: 1/18/13 6:02 PM < 1/20/01 5:00 PM

Obviously today is greater than 1/20/01 but this is the result of my test.  Why?

I have done some searching and saw that the compare member function might be used but it returns an error for me and compare is not in the intelisense (or whatever Lotus calls it) in the design editor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found this little snippet on line - it should point you in the right direction

```
var doc:NotesDocument = varRowView.getDocument();
var d:NotesDateTime = doc.getItemValue("BidDueDate")[0];
var t:NotesDateTime = session.createDateTime("Today");
if (d.timeDifference(t) > 0 ) {
return "Overdue";
}else{
return "";
}
```

Comment: Now why didn't I think of that! :)

Comment: you could also take a look here: http://www.jeroensomhorst.eu/uncategorized/dont-forget-the-milliseconds-a-post-about-dates-and-datetime-comparison/